# MVC3 WebGrid Page/Sort Issue with a CheckBox elsewhere on the page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox, webgrid

I have a checkbox on my page, created as such:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.MyBoolValue)
```

Beneath that I have a WebGrid with sorting and paging, but on doing this I get a System.InvalidOperationException:

```
The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'System.Boolean' failed. See the inner exception for more information.
```

The inner exception is:

```
{"true,false is not a valid value for Boolean."}
```

I know this is due to the binding of the CheckBox and the underlying Hidden value. On a page GET I deal with this using Contains("true") on the query string value, but how can I do this when the WebGrid is refreshed?

Comment: Take a look at this post: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234623/asp-net-mvc-webgrid-is-not-properly-passing-current-parameters-to-the-pagination

Answer (score 3):

MVC creates two inputs on `@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.MyBoolValue)`. One Checkbox and one hidden field with the value `false`.

He (MVC ;)) does this ensure that, even if you dont check the checkbox, the variable exists.
So if you check the box the variable value is `true,false` and `false` if not.

do this:

```
<input type="CheckBox" name="MyBoolValue" value="@Model.MyBoolValue"/>
```

or create a custom model binder that handles that.

[ASP.NET MVC Custom Model Binding](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=584)

Comment: Excellent, I knew it would be something simple. I searched Google but had so many hits about checkbox columns within the WebGrid - not that useful for my issue. Thanks.

Comment: B*gg*r, I've just set the ajaxUpdateContainerId property on the WebGrid and this causes the same issue, even with Html.CheckBox()... any ideas?

Comment: Yes, use a normal html input for that, ive changed my answer. hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've been working on this issue recently and made some other discoveries. If it helps I've documented it here - http://websitesorcery.com/post/2012/03/19/CheckBox-Issue-with-MVC-3-WebGrid-Paging-Sorting.aspx

Comment: This doesn't work for me, the checkbox is not properly bound to the model, and checking the checkbox will not return true in the property on postback.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain all standard validators or binders functionality and hidden field bother you someway. You can use this:

```
<input type="CheckBox"@(Model.BoolProperty ? " checked=\"checked\"" : string.Empty) name="BoolProperty" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that removing the value from the ModelState resolves this, and doesn't seem to cause any side effects - perhaps someone could point out if I've missed anything?

In my controller I just add

```
ModelState.Remove("MyBoolValue");
```

Which means that

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.MyBoolValue)
```

will fallback to using the Model value unless I'm mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the name of your action parameter:

```
public ActionResult Product(ProductModel model);
```

For example the following will fix your issue:

```
public ActionResult Product(ProductModel request);
```

Comment: Care to provide detail as to why it will fix  the issue?