# ASP.NET MVC WebGrid is not properly passing current parameters to the pagination links in a particular situation

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

`WebGrid` pagination links work properly in all cases, except one (that I noticed).

When you use `CheckBoxFor` in MVC, it creates an `input[type=hidden]` and an `input[type=check-box]` for the same field so that it can handle state. So, if you have a field named `X` and submit your form in the `GET` method, you will end up with an URL like this:

> http://foo.com?X=false&X=true

The default model binder can understand these multiple instances os `X` and figure out it's value.

The problem occurs when you try to paginate the `WebGrid`. It's behavior is to try catch the current request parameters and repass them in the pagination links. However, as there's more than one `X`, it will pass `X=false,true` instead of the expected `X=false` or `X=false&X=true`

That's a problem because `X=false,true` won't bind properly. It will trigger an exception in the model binder, prior to the beggining of the action.

Is there a way I can solve it?

**EDIT:**

It seems like a very specific problem but it's not. Nearly every search form with a check box will break the WebGrid pagination. (If you are using GET)

**EDIT 2:**

I think my only 2 options are:

- Build my own WebGrid pager that is more clever on passing parameters for pagination links
- Build my own Boolean model binder that understands `false,true` as valid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case anybody else is suffering from the issue described, you can work around this using a custom model binder like this:

```
public class WebgridCheckboxWorkaroundModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
    {
        if (propertyDescriptor.PropertyType == typeof (Boolean))
        {
            var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(propertyDescriptor.Name);
            if (value.AttemptedValue == "true,false")
            {
                PropertyInfo prop = bindingContext.Model.GetType().GetProperty(propertyDescriptor.Name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                if (null != prop && prop.CanWrite)
                {
                    prop.SetValue(bindingContext.Model, true, null);
                }
                return;
            }
        }

        base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had already implemented exactly this solution. Accepted your answer anyway, as it in fact solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to inheriting from the DefaultModelBinder would be to implement the IModelBinder interface specifically for nullable boolean values.

```
internal class BooleanModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // Get the raw attempted value from the value provider using the ModelName
        var param = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (param != null)
        {
            var value = param.AttemptedValue;
            return value == "true,false";
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can then add the model binding to the Global.asax or add it to the parameter like so:

```
public ActionResult GridRequests([ModelBinder(typeof(BooleanModelBinder))]bool? IsShowDenied, GridSortOptions sort, int? page)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who would like to implement the custom model binder in Dan's solution, but aren't sure how.

You have to register the model binder in the Global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(HomeViewModel), new WebgridCheckboxWorkaroundModelBinder());
    }
```

And also specify its use in your action:

```
public ActionResult Index([ModelBinder(typeof(WebgridCheckboxWorkaroundModelBinder))] HomeViewModel viewModel)
    {
        //code here
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```